# How do we promote this site?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-promotion

One of [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

This is rapidly becoming a hot issue across the entire network:

**How to promote your site and how to reach out to the experts and pundits in your industry.**  We can come up with budgets and promotions but — more than any other issue raised here — the means and ideas about how to reach your target audience HAS TO come from you and your community. Has to. Has to, has to, has to! We simply are not experts in your field. We don’t have the the connections nor the experience you bring to the table. You are both our evangelist and our ambassador.

Feel free to discuss any ideas you have towards promoting the site in this question...

Comment: I am seriously consider a pilot Facebook campaign. Noting big. Maybe just 100$ spread over a week targeting those who like Windows Phone

Comment: How many ad views would that yield? Real promotion would certainly help, but it has to be worth it to do. The ad would have to draw attention and has to be clicked, I don't know how often people do click on them. I've kinda learned to ignore them, but perhaps there might be users that get interested...

Comment: I did a campaign at 50/week for a small app I wrote. I bid $.50/1000 clicks and all 50$ was used up that week. so if all 100 is used that would have been 200,000 clicks. That isn't very much, but even if 1% stay it would help the community. TBH, I'm just interested in seeing how much of an uptick in users we get from something like that.

Comment: @Joe I receive a R$100,00 gift card from Google Adwords. It is something about U$ 50.00. I can give to this cause.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed a lot of developers are on Twitter, and many of them have a number of followers.  Maybe if you find some MS-centric folk that 1) develop, 2) are on twitter and 3) have some followers if you follow them and tweet them softly, asking for some love.  They might give it.

Just sayin'.

Comment: As long as they don't come here for programming questions, I guess such approach is an idea.

Comment: @TomWijsman: was thinking people like Ben "the PC guy", Haack, Hanselman, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I sent a tweet to @windowsphone to see if I can get them to give us a shoutout. That's Microsoft's official twitter for Windows Phone community involvement, and they have a lot of followers, so a mention on there may get us some visibility. Keeping my fingers crossed!

**EDIT**

They haven't by now so I'm assuming they won't. Perhaps they'd be more likely if one of the admins were able to get the official SE twitter to make the suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just a case of promoting the site's existence. There needs to a clear communication of the advantages of sticking around and answering and answering questions. Particularly in terms of answering questions there will need to be a way to persuade people who are already answering questions elsewhere to come here as well (or instead). Why should they make the move?

Comment: I think some people can help in both. Maybe some guys from XDA will answer quastions here like a relex thing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if our name is right in regards to promotion, a site that's named the same as the device makes it hard to use `Windows Phone` on its own as it could lead to confusion. I don't know if having to resort to `Windows Phone on the Stack Exchange Network` or `WindowsPhone.SE` or `WP.SE` are very handy ways to promote the site (and make it stand out, be remembered and so on).

I'm not going to repeat words, but [Gaming.SE's main obstacle is that they don't have a name](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/a-new-name-for-gaming-stack-exchange). Of course they get popular within Stack Exchange because Gaming is something a lot of us (computer fanatics) do, but they did quite some promotion and managed to get a steady activity stream. For events and other forms of advertising, not having a name is painful. They wear `gaming.stackexchange.com` on their chest, now imagine having to wear `windowsphone.stackexchange.com` on your chest, *that's long...*

I think it is important to get this discussion going as early as possible, because if we can get a different name it would benefit us in the long end. If people agree, we can post a meta question in a few days where we try to gather a list of names that fit our site and vote for the one that fits best.

Comment: WinPhone.SE :) But seriously, yes, it would be nice to have a name that stands out

Comment: WP.SE sounds kinda cool. you could use #wpse on twitter (if it's not used by swedish windows phone community ;) ). #wpdev is used by the windows phone development community on twitter. in The Netherlands we use #wp7nl (guess we'll have to remove the 7 there soon)

Comment: is WP too close to WordPress? That is what comes to my mind at @GeertvdC  least

Comment: WinPhone SE reminds me too much of Win 98 SE

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider post-graduation from beta, would be SE Inc suggesting to Microsoft that we be listed on (the admitedly non-obvious to find) [page on the Microsoft site for where to find help](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-GB/howto/contact-us.aspx) (of course, whilst that's the link for my locale, I'd assume that most locales will have similar)