# How do we get more participation in Meta?

Tags: discussion

We need to work through a few discussion here. Mainly:

- [What should our FAQ contain?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-should-our-faq-contain)
- [How do we promote this site?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-we-promote-this-site)
- and a few questions on on/off-topic tags

It seems like we only have the same six or so users here in meta, and as a result not much is getting accomplished. How can we get people over here? How did other SE sites do it? Is it possible to get a banner on the main site with a message like "What should our FAQ contain" with a link to that question?

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### How can we get people over here?

1. **Link to our meta** whenever our meta is relevant, this let's people know that meta is here without necessarily saying "come join us on meta". This is often done for decisions we are taking, but we could as well make FAQ-like meta questions and link to that instead of linking to the FAQ (the meta post would then link to the FAQ).
2. **Invite moderating users to chat / meta** when you see that they are contributing in another way than Q&A and when you see they have no meta participation whatsoever, if they are interested...
3. **The community bulletin** can be set by moderators to include important meta posts, but I'm not certain whether it is present on meta sites though. I also don't see the old meta section anywhere. This might be coming soon though given that it is fairly new...
4. Most importantly, **don't rush meta itself**, we are only a few days out of public beta and you can't expect more people on meta than there are on the main site. **Promotion is more important** such that we get a more active site in the first place, yes the six or so of us will have to go get people over here. We should discuss this in [How do we promote our site?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37/25)