# Will we be held to the stats?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) we can see that we are well below in two key stats:

3.4 questions per day - *15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work.*

216 - visits/day - *1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work.*

I know some work was done in [promoting](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-we-promote-this-site) the site. So, just looking at the question per day, can you imagine that we can reach this target? Perhaps we launched too soon-Windows Phone has a tiny market share (a couple of percent) and the current version 7.5 is quite limited in functionality.

Will this site be closed if we do not reach those targets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Will this site be closed for not reaching those stats?* No, that alone will not get a site shut down. It doesn't really work that way.

Take a look at this blog post:

[**When will my site graduate?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

This site has only been in beta for 27 days. By time it reaches 90 days, it would be *nice* if the site was rated 'excellent' in the key categories, but *not* having achieved that wont get you shut down.

> *"It takes as long as it takes."*

The big caveat is, once you've reached that 90-day point, we'll be watching for signs of steady progress. Yes, *it takes as long as it takes*, but when a site struggles to maintain any semblance of steady progress, *then* it's time to worry.

I wouldn't obsess too much over the numbers. Generally, when a site is doing poorly and falls into steady decline, you can *feel* it. Still, I *have* written up a bit of a guide to help you grapple with those numbers:

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

Keep using the site; keep asking interesting questions and providing great answers; vet those answer, improve them, and up-vote them; get involved in meta activities to keep this site on track; tell your friends and colleagues — then this site should do fine.

Comment: excellent information. Thanks Robert

Comment: +1 because I didn't know there were more blog posts on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think those starts are a yardstick we can use. In a recent blog post, it was stated that sites will stay in beta for "as long as it takes", and that as long as a site shows progress that is ok.

I recently posted this same question in the chat, but I think the site is still to new to use those stats. Its not even 30 days old! I would I've to hear an SE employee's opinion though.

Spread the word, tell your friends. Oh and for the record, I haven't done the facebook ads yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this site be closed if we do not reach those targets?

Some sites [do grow quiet, get warned and eventually get closed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/), it doesn't happen as strict as you would think but there is a lower border; where as other sites [seem to magically continue to escape this](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/historical-activity-on-area-51) by:

- [Promoting](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/act-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace) their website.
- [Looking whether the current community is fine](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/should-we-broaden-the-scope-of-our-community), or could be merged / improved.
- [Asking more questions](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/call-to-action-ask-more-questions-broaden-our-scope) and trying to broaden the scope a bit.

And if that doesn't work out, you could always [try to start over](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40223/life-improvement).

---

So, while the answers is yes, there is a lot that we can do to **prevent** our site from reaching that point.

Or as I like to put it... *ACT NOW! Or forever hold your peace?*